# Proving or disproving inequality with integers

Tags: inequality

The inputs of my question are the nonnegative integers $a_1$, $a_2$, $A$, $x_1$, $x_2$, $N$ respecting the following relations:

- $0\leq a_1 \leq A$ and $0\leq a_2 \leq A$,
- $x_1\geq 0$ and $x_2\geq 0$,
- $a_1x_1+a_2x_2=N.A$,

and I would like to know if the following inequality is always true,
$$a_1a_2\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{x_1}{a_2N}\right\rfloor\right)\leq A,$$
or to find a counterexample.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: well.. $1+\lfloor\frac{x_1}{a_2N}\rfloor$ is greater than $1$, so the left side is greater than $a_1\cdot a_2$ any choice of $a_1,a_2$ so that $A<a_1\cdot a_2$ will be a counterexample..

Comment: I think you made a typo. Shouldn't there be a $x_2$ in the denominator instead of $a_2$, and if not there, in the mulitplication $a_1a_2$?